# Is my proof of the separability of the closure of the range of a compact operator correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, compact-operators, separable-spaces

I want to prove the following remark (found in https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4400/v19/pensumliste/ela-190523.pdf)

[image]

My attempt:

Since $T$ is a compact operator, $T(B)$ is precompact for every bounded set $B \subseteq X$. Thus, $\overline{T(B)}$ is compact, where $\overline{T(B)}$ denotes the closure of $T(B)$.

Since $T(B) \subseteq T(X)$, $\overline{T(B)} \subseteq \overline{T(X)}$.

Thus, $\overline{T(X)}$ has a compact subset, namely $\overline{T(B)}$.

Since compact sets of metric spaces are always separable, $\overline{T(B)}$ has a countable dense subset $A$.

But then $A \subseteq \overline{T(X)}$ is a countable dense subset, hence $\overline{T(X)}$ is separable.

However, I don't think I used that $H$ is a Hilbert space anywhere, which leads me to believe my solution is wrong.

Comment: "But then $A\subseteq \overline {T(X)}$ is a countable dense subset ... " Dense subset of what? Of $\overline  {T(B)},$ not of $\overline {T(X)}$... The correct way: For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $B_n=\{x\in X: \|x\|<n\}.$  Let $C_n$ be a countable dense subset of $\overline {T(B_n)}.$ Let $D=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}C_n.$  If $p\in \overline {T(X)}$ then for each $m\in \Bbb N$ take some $n_m$  and some $y_m\in T(B_{n_m})$ such that $\|p-y_m\|<1/m,$ and take some $c_m\in C_{m_n}$ such that $\|y_m-c_m\|<1/m$ to  show that $p\in \overline D.$

Comment: $H$ can be any normed space.